# Displaying different content in different browser by javascript if else statement

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, if-statement, safari

In my code I am detecting the browser used and trying to display different `<div>` content depending on it.

But my JavaScript code is not working properly. My web application is built on asp.net and vb.net.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="Server">
    <div class="btn-wrapper" id="regular-content">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uxLoginButton" Text="Login"  />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uxRegister" Text="Register"  />
    </div>
    <div id="safari-content">
        <p>Use another Browser </p>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

So, if the user is using any browser other than Safari then i want to display the content where `<div>`'s id is `regular-content`, and if the user is using Safari then I want to display the content where `<div>`'s id is `safari-browser`.

In my JavaScript code I have detected if the user is using safari.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptContent">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    //document.body.innerHTML = isSafari;
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

This detects the browser properly. If the browser is Safari then the value of `isSafari` is `true` and if not the value is `false`.

```
if (isSafari == "true") {
    document.getElementById("safari-content").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("regular-content").style.display = 'none';
} else {
    document.getElementById("safari-content").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("regular-content").style.display = 'block';
}
```

But this does not work properly. In all cases it shows the regular browser content, i.e. if the user is using Safari he should not see the regular browser content, but he sees the regular browser content, not the Safari content.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `if (isSafari)` should work. You are comparing it with string rather than a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isSafari) {
```

instead of

```
if (isSafari == "true") {
```

Comment: is that the same as if(isSafari === true) ?

Comment: In this case yes as > results in a value of true or false. But generally Javascript developers work with truthy and falsy values. A truthy value satisfies an if conditional but does not necessarily === true. Likewise, a falsy value does not satisfy an if conditional even though it might not === false.

Answer (score 2):

check whether its is returning true as boolean or string as "true" try with omitting double inverted commas